# MySQL. Переменные в запросе

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
UPDATE `users` SET `avatar`= $dd WHERE (`users`.`login` $_COOKIE['login'])
```

При выполнении пишет

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/u565555448/public_html/upload.php on line 17
```

Причём на $_COOKIE['login'] не жалуется, всё отлично работает, если место $dd подставить какое либо значение. Пробывал писать $dd по разному. И в ковычках, и разделял запрос на три части, второй из которых была $dd типо

```
"UPDATE `users` SET `avatar`= ".$dd." WHERE (`users`.`login` $_COOKIE['login'])"
```

Никак не работает

Comment: конкатенацию ты не поставил `\`login\` . $_COOKIE['login']` ......либо равно.......... скорее всего ты хотел написать так `WHERE users.\`login\` =  "$_COOKIE['login']"` ......... итого запрос `"UPDATE \`users\` SET \`avatar\`= ".$dd." WHERE \`login\` ='". $_COOKIE['login']."'"` ........ или `"UPDATE \`users\` SET \`avatar\`= $dd  WHERE \`login\` = {$_COOKIE['login']}"`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Во втором варианте пишет `Unknown column 'Morkoffka' in 'where clause'`, хотя в базе значение есть https://hkar.ru/OHnl

Comment: `Unknown column 'Morkoffka'` означает, что нет такого **столбца**, а не значения.. то есть ты пишешь похоже `WHERE $_COOKIE['login'] = ....`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский не думаю, что глаза меня подводят, но написано https://hkar.ru/OHof

Comment: Кажется фигурные скобки надо окружить одинарными кавычками, дав понять, что это (вставляемое и сравниваемое значение) -- строка.....

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Unknown column 'Morkoffka.jpg' in 'field list'

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский это значение $dd

Comment: ну $dd тоже надо в одинарные кавычки, если это тоже строка.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский а вот теперь всё отлично) спасибо

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский оставьте как ответ, чтобы пометить как решение

Comment: Сразу на будущее: 1) судя по скрину где ты затёр пароль - ты его хранишь в открытом виде... не делай так. Прочитай тему о том, как правильно хранить ... 2) используй mysqli или PDO для работы с БД, потому что нельзя подставлять пользовательские данные сразу в запрос. опасно

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  Я знаю, что хранить пароли в открытом виде не безопасно. Планирую использовать для этого хеш суммы Насчёт второго, спасибо, учту

Answer (score 0):

Так должно работать:

```
"UPDATE users SET avatar = '".$dd."' WHERE login = '".$_COOKIE['login']."'"
```

Comment: таже песня Unknown column 'Morkoffka' in 'where clause'

Comment: `"UPDATE users SET avatar = '".$dd."' WHERE login = '".$_COOKIE['login']."'"`